# Changing an event handler on the fly during async postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous

Is it possible to change an event handler during an async postback?

I tried this

```
 RemoveHandler CloseModalButton.Click, AddressOf MakePayment
 AddHandler CloseModalButton.Click, AddressOf MakeBankPayment
```

but clearly it needs a postback before it's changed.

Is there any other way?

Thanks

Edit - Code added!

```
 Private Sub BankOneOff_ConfirmPayments()
    Try
        RemoveHandler CloseModalButton.Click, AddressOf MakePayment
        AddHandler CloseModalButton.Click, AddressOf MakeBankPayment
        Dim vAmount As Decimal = inputBankOneOffAmount.Value
        Dim vBody As String = "<p>This is will make a one time ACH (eCheck) payment from your bank account</p>"
        vBody += "<p>The amount being debited is $" & Format(vAmount, "###,##0.00") & "</p>"
        If Session("ServiceCharge") = True Then
            Dim vChargePercent As Decimal = Session("ACHFee")
            Dim vCharge As Decimal = Math.Round((vAmount * vChargePercent) / 100, 2)
            vBody += "<p> A Service Charge of $" & Format(vCharge, "###,##0.00") & " will be added</p>"
            vBody += "<p> The total that will be debited from your account is $" & Format(vCharge + vAmount, "###,##0.00") & "</p>"
        End If



        Dim SB As New StringBuilder
        SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
        SB.Append("$('#PaymentConfirmationModal').modal();")
        SB.Append("var vBody = document.getElementById('PaymentConfirmationText');")
        SB.Append("vBody.innerHTML = '" & vBody & "';")
        SB.Append("});")
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "CardWindowOpen", SB.ToString, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim vError As New SendError
        vError.MailError("2032", PageName, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It does require a postback as the `Click` event is triggered from the page. What is the workflow that you're trying to do?

Comment: Let me put that another way. Clearly you are trying to do **something** and you think that changing the event handler will solve it for you. What is the **something** that you're trying to do?

Comment: Use the same confirmation pop-up dialog for two different purposes. If it's loaded from credit cards and 'Make Payment' is clicked it needs to go the CCGateway, and if it's loaded from bank (EFT) it needs to go to BankGateway

Comment: Isn't it then just a matter of retaining state and then branching based on an `If` or `Case` (or equivalent)?

Comment: In the end (with deadlines biting at my heals) I opted just to create another pop-up with a unique handler.

Comment: Thank you for your help :-) Hitting CR for a new line just posts the comment - a little counter-intuitive.